# Choosing the type parameters in generic programming

Tags: c++, stl, typename

I came across this piece of code in [cpp ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

What exactly is the purpose of using `typename Container::value_type` in the above declaration? Will the following not work?

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<T>
> class priority_queue;
```

Comment: In a nutshell; `class` and `typename` can mostly be used interchangeably, but in a few situations `typename` is required, so if you just stick to `typename` you should be good :-)

Comment: @miradulo yes you are right. I'm not wondering why typename is used there. I'm wondering why <typename Container::value_type> is used instead of <T>

Comment: Worth noting that since C++17, it is undefined behavior if `T` and `Container::value_type` are not the same type, as cppref alludes to. This was voted in [LWG 2566](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2566) because of issues like [this question points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128782/what-is-the-use-of-first-template-parameter-in-priority-queue).

Comment: The title of this question is quite misleading if what you are asking is why there is a mismatch of template parameter types.

Comment: So just to clarify: your question isn't about template types or parameterization (as in the title), _or_ about the subtle differences between `typename` and `class` as in your first paragraph. It's just about the practical reason `std::priority_queue` is declared that way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is to be more generic: `Container` is a parameter and it might be a container (parametrized on `T`) whose `value_type` is different from `T`. From the top of my head I dont know a good example, but naively there is also no reason to put that constraint on the used `Container` (ie `value_type` must be `T` in your version).

For the sake of the example, lets say you have a `strange_container` whose `value_type` is `std::pair<T,T>` and you want to instantiate the template with

```
priority_queue<T,strange_container<T>>
```

then your default `Compare = std::less<T>` wouldnt work with that container, while `Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>` would correctly compare pairs.

Note that the above doesnt apply since C++17, as (from [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)):

> The behavior is undefined if T is not the same type as
>   Container::value_type. (since C++17)

So it seems like the signature was choosen with maximum genericity in mind and only later it was realized that this degree of freedom wasnt the best choice. And actually there are good reasons to require `value_type` and `T` to be the same, see eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128782/what-is-the-use-of-first-template-parameter-in-priority-queue) for more on this.

Comment: I understood why typename is needed there. But my confusion is over the use of <typename Container:: typename> instead of just using <T>

Comment: I was just about to add an example like the one you just added. Another good example is a hashmap which usually takes a `value_type` and `key_type`, but the hash function relies on the `key_type`, not the `value_type` or both, so `std::hash` will be specialized using `typename Map::key_type`, instead of say `std::pair<key_type, value_type>`. In the OP's case, `T` could refer to a `std::pair<K, V>`, but `std::less` may only be specialized for `K`

Comment: @user463035818 not my DV but from what I understand your example is undefined behavior since C++17.

Comment: @miradulo yeah just noticed it and added at note

Comment: @Sanket you should update your question to make it clear what you are asking, as this answer seems to be answering the question that is asked in the title.

Comment: @xaxxon how does it answer the question in the title? I thought I am ignoring the question in the title but rather answering the question about why the signature is not just using `std::less<T>` as proposed by OP